# Access - goto a recordset found in a searchbox

Tags: ms-access, search, dao

Okay I am working with Access 2021, VBA programming ist more than a decade ago so I need some basic help.

I'm having

- a table tblMyData with the fields ID, Name, givenName
- a form frmMyForm with those fields
- a pop-up search box which gives the search results in a list box 'lstItems'

if I double-click on a list item, Me.lstItems.Value gives me the actual ID of the record, not the record number.
Now I want the underlying form (frmMyForm) to go to the recordset with this ID.

```
frmMyForm.FindFirst "[ID] LIKE 'Me.lstItems.Value'" 
(which throws me an error, [variable not defined])

or something like
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmMyForm", acGoTo, Me.lstItems.ID 
(which throws me an error, [method or variable not defined])
```

I tried any combination of the above objects, but cannot reside.

Answer (score 1):

If your ID is numeric:

```vb
Me.Recordset.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Me.lstItems.Value   ' E.g. "[ID] = 7"
```

If it is a text:

```vb
Me.Recordset.FindFirst "[ID] = '" & Me.lstItems.Value & "'"   ' E.g. "[ID] = 'abc'"
```

Comment: The string version gives me a "variable not defined error", the numeric version "application- or objectdefined error"

Comment: This all depends where the code is, where the objects are that you are accessing and which variables you have declared. Probably `frmMyForm` should be `Me` instead. But `Me.` can be dropped in most cases, because the properties and methods of the current form are in scope anyway.

Comment: Stupid me. `FindFirst` is a method of the `Recordset`. Correct: `Me.Recordset.FindFirst "some condition"`